# Writing accent grave in università

Tags: typography

i'm attempting to write Università but unsuccessfully.

I have tried this one:

```
                       \centerline{\textbf{Universit\grave{a} degli studi di Roma}}
```

Please can you help me to write correctly `\grave{a}` because it is not running at all on my pdf. Latex does not read it.

Comment: Try `Universit\\`a`. `\grave` is to be used in another context, not this one. And by the way, if you have a proper encoding in the beginning, you can write `Università` directly. A MWE would certainly help. `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda What one should write here to obtain \backslash grave a?

Comment: @Przemysław: ooh now I get it! Now it will be a problem for me to typeset it, hold on: `\\\`` Testing: `\\``.

Comment: If you don't have direct access on your keyboard, you just type a  `backtick + a`, and load `inputenc` with `utf8` option, that's all. `\grave` is an accent for math mode.

Comment: Paulo suggestion is working. Yes now it is working. Thank you very much

Answer (score 5):

As Paulo Cereda said,

```
\centerline{\textbf{Universit\`{a} degli studi di Roma}}
```

Comment: this requires a backslash before the backtick.  (and, strictly speaking, the braces aren't necessary around the "a".)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thank you Barbara! already corrected.

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}

 \centerline{\textbf{Università degli studi di Roma}}

\end{document}
```